# How to keep tabs when adding new lines in python

Tags: python, tabs

So I'm trying to format a list in Python using the .format() method. I want my output to be as follows

```
One
    Two
        Three
            Four
```

However, when I run the following code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    output_str = ''
    my_list = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
    for element in my_list:
        output_str = '{}{}\n\t'.format(output_str, element)
    print (output_str)
```

It prints

```
One
    Two
    Three
    Four
```

Is there a way of making new lines in Python while keeping all tabs made before with .format()?
Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Hint: multiply the string '\t' with the indendation level.

Comment: Works pretty good, Thanks :P. However, I still wonder if there's a way to do it directly with .format() without having to do such tricks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `.format()` can be used to do the indentation by specifying the tab character as the fill character as follows:

```
my_list = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']

for indent_level, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print("{:\t<{i}}{}".format('', element, i=indent_level))
```

This would display:

```
One
    Two
        Three
            Four
```